Content markdown files require server restart to show changes
I created a Nuxt 3 project from the empty template in Nuxt Studio and then cloned the project locally.
Running npm run dev works and the server starts fine, and I can load the index page (content/index.md)
If I make any updates to content/index.md, I expected HMR to refresh the content and show the new text, however it doesn't. If I refresh the page, it also doesn't change it, it only updates when I fully restart the nuxt server and then refresh the page.
I found this which appears to be relevant but no solution there, it only points to this which says to disable caching in browser dev tools, then refreshing the page. I've followed those steps however it still doesn't load the new content when refreshing the page.
As an additional test I made a page change, then loaded a different browser and navigated to my dev server for the first time through that browser, and it still showed the old page content; confirming it's not a browser issue, it must be the server caching the old content.
I've also verified the issue is happening across both the index.md and about.md files. As a further test, I restarted the server, edited the about.md file, then loaded it for the first time in the browser, and it showed the pre-edited version.
Any ideas about how I can get either hot reloading working for the content markdown files, or even have them just work on refreshing the browser, instead of having to restart the web server every time to see updates?
The project structure looks like this:
project/
  content/
    about.md
    index.md
  nuxt.config.ts
  package.json

The nuxt.config.ts contains:
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  modules: ['@nuxt/content'],

  routeRules: {
    '/': { prerender: true }
  },

  compatibilityDate: '2024-10-21'
})

package.json dependencies are:
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxt/content": "^2.13.4",
    "nuxt": "^3.13.2"
  }
}

